# Java Error: unresolved compilation

Tags: java, compiler-errors

When I run the following code I receive the error - 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:

```
at homework6.main(homework6.java:6)
```

I researched why this could occur and previous answers had said the class name needed to match the java file name, my class matches that of the .java file as well. I also tried removing "void" and the entire statement altogether, but then a new error occurred saying I needed public void main(String[] args). Am I encountering a different problem then the class and .java?

```
public class homework6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        class Date {
            private int month;
            private int day;
            private int year;
            private String name;

            public Date() {

            }

            {
                month=1;
                day = 1;
                year = 2001;
                name = "January";
            }

            public Date(int m, int d, int y) {
                setDate(m, d, y);
            }

            public void setDate(int m, int d, int y) {
                month = m;
                day = d;
                year = y;

                if (m ==1 )
                    name="January";
                else if(m == 2)
                    name="February";
                else if(m == 3)
                    name="March";
                else if(m == 4)
                    name="April";
                else if(m == 5)
                    name = "May";
                else if(m == 6)
                    name = "June";
                else if(m == 7)
                    name = "July";
                else if(m == 8)
                    name = "August";
                else if(m == 9)
                    name = "September";
                else if(m == 10)
                    name = "October";
                else if(m == 11)
                    name="November";
                else if(m == 12)
                    name = "December";
            }

            public void showDate1() {
                System.out.println(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
            }

            public void showDate2() {
                System.out.println(name + "" + day + "," + year);
            }

            public void showDate3() {
                System.out.println(day + "" + name + "" + year);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't have a class inside a function. Put it outside your function instead.

Comment: I just copied your code into a file named `homework6.java` -- with that exact capitalization -- and it compiled just fine. It ran without error, too, though it didn't _do_ anything since the only thing your main() method does is to declare a class (not instantiate it, much less invoke any methods on it).

Answer (score 0):

You're nesting a class, `Date`, within a method, the main method to be precise -- something you can't and shouldn't do.

Solution: don't do this.

Create one file called Date.java and place your Date class code in it.
Create a 2nd file called Homework6.java and place your main method in it.

Done.

Comment: This is wrong -- you _can_ nest a class within a method. I double checked just now and verified that on 1.8, though I'm nearly sure it's true in 1.7 as well, and who knows earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Valid points those in the answer. You could alternatively just put the class outside the main and get it to compile.

If you take a step back though, and assuming you get this code to compile, what would be the expected output? You seem to make no calls to any methods. Do you want to spend a moment in understanding your logic?

Comment: How would you suggest I put the class outside the main? Do I include from class date to "name="January?"

Answer (score 0):

Probably because of this:

```
public Date() {

}

{
    month=1;
    day = 1;
    year = 2001;
    name = "January";
}
```

The first two brackets should be removed, because the code between the second two is not in a method. So it should be like this:

```
public Date() {
    month=1;
    day = 1;
    year = 2001;
    name = "January";
}
```